# Ubuntu 16.04: Wifi connection to a new network fails

Tags: 16.04, wireless

For some reason I cannot connect my laptop to "unknown" wifi networks anymore, meaning: if I already got connected to the wifi network and saved the password then it connects perfectly, but if I have to connect to a new network and put in the password for the first time, it's impossible.

Actually I simply don't have the box of identification where I am supposed to put the password, the only message that I have is "activation of the connection failed".

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried `wicd`? Please see this: https://askubuntu.com/a/158699/248467

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work ! I Should I uninstall network-manager then ?

Comment: If you want to. But have you checked that WICD is working correctly after a reboot? If yes then you may proceed to remove `network-manager`. But you should first download a copy of `network-manager` and keep it on your system in case `wicd` somehow fails to work in the future (for any reason).

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=NetworkManager&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile#No_prompt_for_password_of_secured_Wi-Fi_networks

Comment: in fact the solution of Manish is not working. @ArpitAgarwal : gnome-keyring is already installed.

Comment: uninstalling gnome-keyring and reinstalling it solved definitely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If you need restart network manager